# Selecting a Design Pattern in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, design-patterns, facade

The below code I modified from Multiple Inheritance to Facade Data Pattern , however it is still breaking the concept of the Facade Data pattern as my subsystems(ES) are sharing amongst themselves . 
All the ES are working on a Structured data stream and enriching the data together , they all are run in Async and then gathered into a list (using async gather) . I wanted to know which data pattern suits this

Used case ,

1. Where I can keep adding ES as per my requirement.
2. Each ES can share data amongst itself like dictonary .
3. And I if I have to add new functionality I follow "Single Responsibility Principle"

Multiple Inheritance

```
import os
import asyncio
import psycopg2
import websockets
from datetime import datetime
from websockets.extensions import permessage_deflate
from structure import Structure
import sys
sys.path.append('..')
from event_stations.es3a import ES3A
from event_stations.es3b import ES3B
from event_stations.es3c import ES3C
from event_stations.es3d import ES3D
from event_stations.es1a import ES1A
from event_stations.es1b import ES1B
from event_stations.es2a import ES2A
from event_stations.es2b import ES2B

class FR_Server(ES1A, ES2A, ES2B, ES3A, ES3B, ES3C, ES3D, Structure):
    unique_id = "100"
    event_format_list = []
    fr_config_table = 'detail_event.app_fer_config'
    psql_db = None

    def __init__(self):
        print("Receiver Called INIT")
        self.psql_db = self.connect_to_psql()
        self._get_metadata()
        super(FR_Server, self).__init__()
        # self.start_receiver(self.mapped_dict)

    def connect_to_psql(self):
        db = psycopg2.connect("dbname=trimble user=postgres password=admin")
        return db

    def _get_parent_classname(self):
        _parent_classes = []
        _cls_obj = eval("FR_Server")
        for parent in _cls_obj.__bases__:
            _parent_classes.append(parent.__name__)
        return _parent_classes

    def _get_metadata(self):
        _parents = self._get_parent_classname()
        print(_parents, "pppp")
        cur = self.psql_db.cursor()
        cur.execute(f"Select * from {self.fr_config_table}")
        results = cur.fetchall()
        for result in results:
            event_station_id = result[0]
            if event_station_id in _parents:
                event_station_classname = eval(event_station_id)                
                setattr(event_station_classname, "cache_table_name", result[1])
                setattr(event_station_classname, "ignite_port", result[2])
                setattr(event_station_classname, "ignite_host", result[3])


    def get_port(self):
        return os.getenv('WS_PORT', '10011')

    def get_host(self):
        return os.getenv('WS_HOST', 'localhost')

    async def start(self):
        return await websockets.serve(self.handler, self.get_host(), self.get_port(), ping_interval=None, max_size=None,
                                max_queue=None, close_timeout=None, extensions=[
                permessage_deflate.ServerPerMessageDeflateFactory(
                    server_max_window_bits=11,
                    client_max_window_bits=11,
                    compress_settings={'memLevel': 4},
                ),
            ])

    def generate_event_id(self, index):
        return  "".join(['%02d%02d%d%d%d%d%d' % (datetime.now().day, datetime.now().month, datetime.now().year,
                                                datetime.now().hour,datetime.now().minute, datetime.now().second,
                                                datetime.now().microsecond), self.unique_id,index])

    async def handler(self, websocket, path):
        async with websockets.connect('ws://localhost:10015', ping_interval=None, max_size=None,
                                      max_queue=None, close_timeout=None,
                                      extensions=[permessage_deflate.ClientPerMessageDeflateFactory(
                                          server_max_window_bits=11,
                                          client_max_window_bits=11,
                                          compress_settings={'memLevel': 4},
                                      ),
                                      ]) as websocket_rb:

            async for row in websocket:
                lst_row = row.decode().split(",")
                uid = self.generate_event_id(lst_row[0])
                lst_row = [uid] + lst_row
                results = await asyncio.gather(self.enrich_column_es3a_dict(lst_row[1]),
                                               self.enrich_column_es3b_dict(lst_row[1]),
                                               self.enrich_column_es3c_dict(lst_row[1]),
                                               self.enrich_column_es3d_dict(lst_row[1]))
                await websocket_rb.send(str(lst_row + results).encode())

    def start_receiver(self, mapped_list):
        self.event_format_list = mapped_list
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(self.start())
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Facade Data pattern :

```
from __future__ import annotations
from event_stations.es1a import ES1A
from event_stations.es2a import ES2A
from event_stations.es2b import ES2B
import psycopg2

class Foundation_Facade(object):
    psql_db = None
    client = None

    def __init__(self, es1a: ES1A, es2a: ES2A) -> None:
        self._es1a = es1a or ES1A()
        self._es2a = es2a or ES2A()

    def operation(self):
        print("Called")
        results = []
        self.psql_db = self._es1a._connect_psql()   

        self._es1a._get_metadata(self.psql_db.cursor())
        self.client = self._es1a.connect_ignite_client(self._es1a.ignite_host, self._es1a.ignite_port)

        self._es2a._get_metadata(self.psql_db.cursor())
        self._es2a.put_data(self.client)

        self._es2b._get_metadata(self.psql_db.cursor())
        self._es2b.put_data(self.client)

        print(self._es2b.static_df.head())
        # results.append(self._es1a._get_metadata())
        return results


if __name__ == '__main__':
    es1a = ES1A()
    es2a = ES2A()
    es2b = ES2B()
    facade = Foundation_Facade(es1a, es2a)    
    from fr_server_1 import Server
    Server(facade)
```